# Exact cause if two can messages with same ID at same time txs

Tags: can-bus

plz can anyone help me out what exactly will happen if two can messages of same IDS and transmitting at same time with diff payload/same payload??? need to know little depth!!!

Answer (score 2):

In case the arbitration fields are identical, but data is different, the first transmitter that attempts to send a recessive bit but detects a dominant bit instead, will flag for bit error and the data frame will be rejected.

If two nodes attempt to send a message with identical identifier and payload, neither transmitter will complain and the message will be sent successfully.

[Duplicate of this question at electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/43150/6102).